# Change Docker image file system

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops, xfs

I want to change the docker image(Any images such as Database images: MongoDB or PostgreSQL) to XFS file system.
Is there any solution such as set options into the Docker file to change the file system of any docker images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers are not virtual machines, where that would be possible.

They use an overlay file system that enables Docker's image layering functionality. This is a fundamental foundation for Docker to work, and you cannot use other filesystems to base containers on.